# Object equality issue after babelification in Next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babeljs, next.js

I have a React project build with Next.js. I added the [React Simple Dropdown](https://github.com/Fauntleroy/react-simple-dropdown) module and am just using the basic sample author provides. All works fine. Now I would like to copy the 3 dropdown files from the module and modify them. So I copied the `src` files to my components directory and changed my line in my code from:

```
import Dropdown, { DropdownTrigger, DropdownContent } from 'react-simple-dropdown'
```

to:

```
import Dropdown, { DropdownTrigger, DropdownContent } from './Dropdown/Dropdown'
```

This causes this [line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uCjSy.png) to no longer work: `if (child.type === DropdownTrigger)`.

Inspecting the `child.type` I see a difference (top is my code):

[image: my code]

[image: original code]

It seems that my Next.js webpack is handling things differently than whatever tool the author use to babelify the original code. I am able to handle the match in other ways but would like to understand what is happening. It seems related so some default export but I am not clear why things are different and what Babel setting handles this.

Comment: I guess you have 2 `DropdownTrigger` imported somehow. Then on this [line](https://github.com/Fauntleroy/react-simple-dropdown/blob/master/src/components/Dropdown.jsx#L85), your `DropdownTrigger` is not properly identified. As a consequence, `onClick` prop is not added.

Comment: @wesley6j I don't think so. I just logged the looping of the `boundChildren` on that file. They both generate one `DropdownTrigger` and one `DropdownContent` each save that the trigger on my local copy has no `ref` and `onClick`. I added shots to my post.

Comment: It would probably be helpful to include the source code where you create the DropdownTrigger in render

Comment: Could you add a console log [here](https://github.com/Fauntleroy/react-simple-dropdown/blob/master/src/components/Dropdown.jsx#L86) inside the if block. I want to see if this part is triggered at least once.

Comment: From the fact that both `ref` and `onClick` are missing, I am sure `DropdownTrigger` is not recognised properly.

Comment: @AndyRay - I use the sample from the module https://github.com/Fauntleroy/react-simple-dropdown

Comment: @wesley6j - it logs to console ok. I can see it match the type, build the child with the ref/onClick and pass that on. Just doesn't end up in my code. Exact same code works when path is in node_modules library which leads me to think its a Nextjs/webpack/SSR thing

Comment: @wesley6j Edited question to better reflect issue

Comment: As I said, you are importing `DropdownTrigger` from two different places. This is confusing and not necessary. They will not be equal even if babel compiles them the same way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Evidently class comparison [doesn't work](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/9652) with React Hot Loader in dev mode. Known issue with no fix at the moment. So using `item.type.displayNane === 'DropdownTrigger'` would be a workaround.